# How can I type this parameters from Knex Config?

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, knex.js

I am having issues trying to type the function parameters in this line of code:

```
pool: {
  afterCreate: (conn, cb) => conn.run('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', cb),
},
```

Entire file code:

```
import { knex as setupKnex, Knex } from 'knex'
import { env } from './env'

export const config: Knex.Config = {
  client: env.DATABASE_CLIENT,
  connection: {
    filename: env.DATABASE_URL,
  },
  useNullAsDefault: true,
  pool: {
    afterCreate: (conn, cb) => conn.run('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON', cb),
  },
  migrations: {
    extension: 'ts',
    directory: './src/database/migrations',
  },
}

export const knex = setupKnex(config)
```

Should I just use any to type the params?

I tried going to the types file of the Knex framework, however they type afterCreate: function without typing the params. For example:

```
interface PoolConfig {
    name?: string;
    afterCreate?: function;
    min?: number;
    max?: number;
    refreshIdle?: boolean;
    idleTimeoutMillis?: number;
    reapIntervalMillis?: number;
    returnToHead?: boolean;
    priorityRange?: number;
    log?: (message: string, logLevel: string) => void;
```